# PHP's mail function seems to remove newlines and tabs

Tags: php, email, newline, line-breaks

I have this helper class which I use to send E-Mails through PHP:

```
<?php

class Mailsend {

    public $from;
    public $to;
    public $subject;
    public $message;

    public static function mail() {
        return new Mailsend();
    }

    public function from($from) {
        $this->from = $from;
        return $this;
    }

    public function fromName($fromName) {
        $this->fromName = $fromName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function to($to) {
        $this->to = $to;
        return $this;
    }

    public function subject($subject) {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        return $this;
    }

    public function message($message) {
        $this->message = $message;
        return $this;
    }

    public function send() {
        $mailFrom = $this->from;
        $mailFromName = $this->fromName;
        $mailTo = $this->to;
        $mailSubject = $this->subject;

        $mailSignature = "\n\n-- \n";
        $mailSignature .= "Vaš, Format.ba - Primjenjene Vještine.\n";
        $mailSignature .= "Za više informacija posjetite nas na: http://www.format.ba/\n";

        $mailBody = $this->message . "\n";
        $mailBody .= $mailSignature;

        $mailHeader = "From: $mailFromName <$mailFrom>\r\n";
        $mailHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $mailHeader .= "Reply-To: $mailFromName <$mailFrom>\r\n";
        $mailHeader .= "X-Mailer: Mailsend.php\r\n";
        $mailHeader .= "X-Sender-IP: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}\r\n";
        $mailHeader .= "Bcc: $mailFromName <$mailFrom>\r\n";

        $mailParams = "-f$mailFrom";

        $mailBody = str_replace('  ', '', $mailBody);

        return mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailBody, $mailHeader, $mailParams);
    }

    public function valid($email) {
        if (!preg_match("/^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$/", $email)) {
            return false;
        }
        $email_array = explode("@", $email);
        $local_array = explode(".", $email_array[0]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($local_array); $i++) {
            if (!preg_match("/^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$/", $local_array[$i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (!preg_match("/^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$/", $email_array[1])) {
            $domain_array = explode(".", $email_array[1]);
            if (sizeof($domain_array) < 2) {
                return false;
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($domain_array); $i++) {
                if (!preg_match("/^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])|([A-Za-z0-9]+))$/", $domain_array[$i])) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

It works and I wrote it so it is easy to use, like this for an instance:

```
$message = "Hello, " . $model->fullname . ",

                        Welcome to our Website, Domain.tdl. You are now able to use all of our services which we provide here.

                        Visit: www.domain.tdl - for more information and news about our services!

                        Greets!";

Mailsend::mail()->
    from('info@domain.tdl')->
    fromName('Domain.tdl - Our Website')->
    to('someother@email.tdl')->
    subject('Welcome to Domain.tdl - Our Website')->
    message(trim($message))->send();
```

And as you can see from this exact example there is alot of whitespace which is indented by "empty spaces", not tabs.

And when I send that message to one of my E-Mails, I get this output:

> Hello, Zlatan Welcome to our Website, Domain.tdl. You are now able to
>   use all of our services which we provide here. Visit: www.domain.tdl -
>   for more information and news about our services! Greets!

It just somehow strips all the newlines and more-than-two-in-length whitespaces, and merges them all together, so I lose my originally intended E-Mail format.

I have tought that this line in the `Mailsend` might cause the problem:

```
$mailBody = str_replace('  ', '', $mailBody);
```

But that's not the case, and so far I have not find any reasons why this accours and could not prevent it going on.

Has anyone expirenced something similar? Is it possible that I'm missing something in my own code?

Comment: and yes... before anyone flags this one as a possible duplicate... none of the answers I've found on STO which are somewhat dealing with the same problem, did not helped me!

Comment: No, it doesn't remove it. But you're assuming that the client will respect those tabs and spaces (which is wrong)

Comment: how to you read the email? can it be that your email reader causes the problem?

Comment: @zerkms belive me, that's not my biggest problem at the moment :) I want to solve the issue which accours, the issue I have explained in detail in this question! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl - gmail causing problems? impossible... I even use it's SMTP to deliver the mail :)

Comment: Meaning that you are reading the email via GMail's web interface, yes?

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, of course! via gmail.com

Comment: @Zlatan O.: I will repeat once again: `mail()` doesn't stripe anything, the spaces and tabs are there in email. But html client does collapse several whitespaces into a single one.

Comment: Make sure that you are using 'text/plain' as the content type

Comment: @zerkms - it's because of the headers! and it should be HTML, not plain text in it! I should just now do the <code>nl2br</code>, and End-Of-Story!

Comment: @Zlatan O.: it's not about headers. You're sending html and assume that in HTML multiple spaces will be rendered as multiple spaces. But that's wrong. That's HTML basics actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this with `<br>`

```
$message = "Hello, " . $model->fullname . "<br>,

                    Welcome to our Website, Domain.tdl. You are now able to use all of our services which we provide here.<br>

                    Visit: www.domain.tdl - for more information and news about our services!<br>

                    Greets!";
```

Comment: should I modify headers for mail function?

Comment: @ZlatanO. No there is no need.

Comment: silly me! I haven't even noticed that this is the text/html output format, until now!

Comment: nl2br :) did the magic trick! thank you for your guidence! I will accept your answer in about 2-3 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

Use `<br />` instead of `\r\n`.

Add this header in order to make your content HTML formatted:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

When you want to insert tabs, use multiple `&nbsp;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the following header:

```
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

but are about to send plain text emails. Change it to

```
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

or format your email as html